# Mysql - get n number of results from grouped data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get random N results per group by records, and the query is not working,

```
  SELECT `img_url`
   FROM
     (SELECT img_url, 
                  @image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS image_rank,
                  @current_category := category_child 
       FROM images
       ORDER BY category_child, rand()
     ) ranked
   WHERE image_rank <= 5
```

When I run the subquery image_rank is always 1, I have more then 1000 images per category and 30 categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post `@country_rank` should be `@image_rank`. Also the initialization of the used `user variables` are added in `CROSS JOIN`.

To get the rand N selection, the `ORDER BY rand()` should be before the `image_rank` generation.

```
SELECT category_child, `img_url`, image_rank
FROM
 (SELECT img_url, 
           @image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @image_rank + 1, 1) AS image_rank,
           @current_category := category_child AS category_child
   FROM (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY category_child, rand()) AS images_rand CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT @image_rank := 0, @current_category := NULL) param
 ) ranked
WHERE image_rank <= 5;
```

Here is a demo:

## SQL:

```
-- data
create table images( category_child int, img_url char(20));
insert into images values
(1,'d'),(1,'c'),(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'x'),(1,'s'),
(2,'d'),(2,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'x'),(2,'s');
select * from images;

-- Query wanted
SELECT category_child, `img_url`, image_rank
FROM
 (SELECT img_url, 
           @image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @image_rank + 1, 1) AS image_rank,
           @current_category := category_child AS category_child
   FROM (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY category_child, rand()) AS images_rand CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT @image_rank := 0, @current_category := NULL) param
 ) ranked
WHERE image_rank <= 5;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from images;
+----------------+---------+
| category_child | img_url |
+----------------+---------+
|              1 | d       |
|              1 | c       |
|              1 | a       |
|              1 | b       |
|              1 | x       |
|              1 | s       |
|              2 | d       |
|              2 | c       |
|              2 | a       |
|              2 | b       |
|              2 | x       |
|              2 | s       |
+----------------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Query wanted
mysql> SELECT category_child, `img_url`, image_rank
    -> FROM
    ->  (SELECT img_url,
    ->            @image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @image_rank + 1, 1) AS image_rank,
    ->            @current_category := category_child AS category_child
    ->    FROM (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY category_child, rand()) AS images_rand CROSS JOIN
    ->       (SELECT @image_rank := 0, @current_category := NULL) param
    ->  ) ranked
    -> WHERE image_rank <= 5;
+----------------+---------+------------+
| category_child | img_url | image_rank |
+----------------+---------+------------+
|              1 | s       |          1 |
|              1 | x       |          2 |
|              1 | b       |          3 |
|              1 | c       |          4 |
|              1 | d       |          5 |
|              2 | b       |          1 |
|              2 | s       |          2 |
|              2 | x       |          3 |
|              2 | c       |          4 |
|              2 | a       |          5 |
+----------------+---------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Run again and generate different rand selection
mysql> SELECT category_child, `img_url`, image_rank
    -> FROM
    ->  (SELECT img_url,
    ->            @image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @image_rank + 1, 1) AS image_rank,
    ->            @current_category := category_child AS category_child
    ->    FROM (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY category_child, rand()) AS images_rand CROSS JOIN
    ->       (SELECT @image_rank := 0, @current_category := NULL) param
    ->  ) ranked
    -> WHERE image_rank <= 5;
+----------------+---------+------------+
| category_child | img_url | image_rank |
+----------------+---------+------------+
|              1 | x       |          1 |
|              1 | c       |          2 |
|              1 | d       |          3 |
|              1 | a       |          4 |
|              1 | s       |          5 |
|              2 | a       |          1 |
|              2 | c       |          2 |
|              2 | s       |          3 |
|              2 | d       |          4 |
|              2 | x       |          5 |
+----------------+---------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In your post country_rank should be image_rank - was typo. still rank for all results are return as 1 after adding CROSS JOIN ... param, is this has anything to do with mysql version?  edited with mysql version

Answer (score 0):

When using variables in MySQL, you should not set them in one expression and use them in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  So, you need to put the variable manipulations in a single expression.  In addition, you should initialize the variables:

```
SELECT `img_url`
FROM (SELECT img_url, 
             (@image_rank := IF(@current_category = category_child, @image_rank + 1,
                                IF(@current_category := category_child, 1, 1)
                               )
             ) AS image_rank                  
     FROM images i CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT @current_category := '', @image_rank := 0) params
     ORDER BY category_child, rand()
    ) ranked
WHERE image_rank <= 5;
```